# jQuery load order between DOM, JSON and Functions

Tags: jquery, json, html

I bought a HTML5 template and I am trying to load the dynamic content via JSON, instead of leaving it static. The problem is: the template has javascript methods that require the DOM fully loaded to work. I'm trying to find the correct load order, but I can't figure out. The template starts with:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  initOutdoor();
  initparallax();
});
```

The initOutdoor function looks like:

```
function initOutdoor() {
  "use strict";
  $(window).load(function() {
      "use strict";
      $(".loader").fadeOut(500, function() {
        $("#main").animate({
            opacity: "1"
        });
      });
      initgalheight();
  });   
  initgalheight();
  // css ------------------
  $(".hero-title , .team-social , .srtp ul , .slide-title , .scroll-page-nav , .count-folio").addClass("cdc");
  function a() {
    ...
```

I'm trying to add a loadData() method, that loads a JSON and populate the DOM with content. I need to do that before these 2 methods. I tried to callback like this:

```
function loadData(function() {
  initOutdoor();
  initparallax();
});
```

But it's not working (maybe beacuse of the $(window).load call?). How can I do that?

Comment: What errors are you seeing?

Comment: No errors on console, but all functions inside initOutdoor and initparallax functions (like a() in the example) are not applied to the dynamic content. The main menu (when the screen size is small) is not dropping down, the caroussel is gone and so on...

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the functions in a `$(document).ready({});` callback? That will wait until the page loads. You also don't need to apply `"use strict";` inside of each function. That declaration should be line 1 of your JS file and you're good to go after that.